# SonarQube is giving "Either log or rethrow this exception." error

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

In my code I am logging the actual exception but still SonarQube is giving `Either log or rethrow this exception.` error. Any idea why SQube is giving such error ?
Please help.
Code:

```
finally {
            if (testJmxConnection != null) {
                try {
                    testJmxConnection.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.error("Couldnt close statement" + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
```

SonarQube Version : 5.8

Comment: SonarQube (like any other such quality tool) is not perfect. Mark it as a false positive and carry on.

Comment: which logging framework do you use, does sonarqube support it? or maybe you are using some kind of abstraction, which sonarqube is not aware of?

Comment: 5.8 is not a version of SonarQube : What is the version of your server and more importantly, what is the version of SonarJava installed on it ?